# Google cloud debugger not displaying source code

Tags: google-cloud-debugger

I'm using Google App Engine and I've followed the instruction to setup Google Debugger as show here:
https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/nodejs

My project is written in Node.js and I'm starting the service with this line:

```
require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({serviceContext: {enableCanary: true}});
```

I've also generated the source-context file.

When I go to the debugger console (https://console.cloud.google.com/debug) I see the green tick about the debug agent running but nothing is displayed on the left side, under "Deployed files".

[image: screenshot added]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if you have added this line `require('@google-cloud/debug-agent').start({serviceContext: {enableCanary: true}});` at the top of the file in your entrypoint script.
And this is the instruction given in google cloud docs - *Enable the agent at the top of your app's main script or entry point (but after @google/cloud-trace if you are also using it)*.

Comment: Hi @crivella, I was able to reproduce the issue that you're facing but can you please submit a screenshot of what you're encountering to be aligned to what I reproduced. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MarcAnthonyB, I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @RajKumarN , I've added the line at the top of my first file (start.js)

Comment: Okay, did you try selecting your source repo manually. Please refer to this page for more details - https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/source-options#cloud-source-repo @crivella

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is intended behavior. Deployments to **App Engine Standard** will show the source code as the source files are included on deployment and not using a Docker container while deployments to **App Engine Flex** are using a Docker container, which currently need not to include the source files, hence why you need a source context information which is generated from a Git Repository. For more information about differences of standard and flex, please see [Choose an App Engine environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments).

For App Engine Flex app source code to appear on Cloud Debugger, it must be located on a remote code hosting provider. Make sure that you follow the [Selecting source code automatically](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/source-context) properly. Your main source code (`js`, `yaml`, and `source-context.json`)  should be in the root directory of the repository as shown below.

```
App-directory/
  main.py
  app.yaml
  source-context.json
```

I've successfully deployed sample application using Github showing the source codes on the left side as shown below.
[image: Debugger]
**Some important notes:**

When using "Cloud Source Repositories" or "GitHub" or any of the other remote code hosting options, one must take some care:

- Changes to the source file must be committed to version control before running `gcloud debug source gen-repo-info-file`.
- `gcloud debug source gen-repo-info` must be run before deploying the App.
- Commits must have been pushed to Cloud Source Repository/GitHub/etc before running Cloud Debugger.
- Access must have been granted to the repo to the Cloud Debugger application.
- Always redeploy application when there are changes to the repository or source code.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Anthony B for your reply. I don't share all this complexity to be able to use a tool as important as the cloud debugger but at least I understood why it didn't work.

There is only one problem: as a GitHub user I am part of many organizations and when from GCloud I select "GitHub" it allows me to select only the personal repos, not those of the organizations I belong to. So in the end, it doesn't work

Comment: @crivella I don't know your full use case but if Flex doesn't work, then I suggest using Standard. In addition, if you think this feature should be added, please submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187252&template=1162896) here.

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo flex and standard environments have big differences and I can't change so easily from flex to standard.